# after running macro return to same cell in all windows

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file where I usually have multiple windows open. Typically in one window I have sheet1 active, in the second window I have sheet2 active etc. I have written a macro where in several steps, different sheets are selected. After running my macro I want to have the same sheet (and cell) selected as before running the macro. Usually I would do this with the following code:

```
Dim CellX As Range

Set CellX = ActiveCell

' run the macro

Application.Goto CellX
```

However, this does not work if I use multiple windows, only one window goes to the right posistion after running the macro. Does anyone know how to do this?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think it shouldn't be happened, but you may try this ..

```
Set CellX = ActiveSheet!ActiveCell
```

But .. what's in your macro code ?

Comment: Hi Matzone, thanks for the quick response.
When I use your code, I get an error message.

Comment: Too quick to hit the enter button.... I found out that the reason that all windows go to the sheet that was originally active was indeed because of my own code. Without the 'Application.Goto CellX', only in the originally active window another sheet became active.

You requested for my code, I know you will probably tell me that for most situations there is an easy way to avoid making a different sheet active. You are right, but the problem I have actually exists in about 20 macro's, there is no time to change all these macro's :).

Answer (score 0):

I found out that Application.Goto was the cause that in all windows the original sheet and cell of CellX where selected. I found the following solution:

```
Dim CellX As Range
Dim SheetX As String
Dim RangeX As Range
Set CellX = ActiveCell
Set RangeX = Range(CellX, CellX)
SheetX = ActiveSheet.Name
'run macro
Worksheets(SheetX).Activate
RangeX.Activate
```

I realise that this can be 'prettyfied', but at least I have a working solution now.